# Finding all Indices of a number from an Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Say I have an array of:

```
int [] I = { 1, 3, 6, 3, 7,3, 9, 3};
int value = 3;
```

I have a for loop that tracks the amount of occurences of the value:

```
int counter = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < I.length; x++)
{
    if(I[x] == value)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I make a new array with length equal to the number of occurrences, that can store all the indices of the occurences from the original array:

```
int [] index = new int [counter];

for(int x = 0; x < index.length; x++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<I.length; i++) 
    {
        if(I[i] == value){
           index[x] = i;
        }       
    }
}
```

However, when I print my array of indices, i just get the last index printed the amount of times counter is equal to, when I want all the indices.

```
for(int i = 0; i<index.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(index[i]);
}
```

It just prints "7" (the last index) 3 times. How do I go about fixing this so I have an array of all indices?
Thank you.

Comment: your logic to find indexes is incorrect . Use print statements or debugger to step into your program to find issues in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `for` loop should not be nested; you should only increment `x` when you find a match. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < I.length; i++) {
    if (I[i] == value) {
        index[x] = i;
        x++;
    }
}
```

Assuming you're using Java 8+, you could have written a `filter()` on the range of indices in the array. Like,

```
int[] index = IntStream.range(0, I.length).filter(i -> I[i] == value).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the outer *for* loop and store into the `index` array as you iterate through the original array `I`. The problem with your code is that, since you repeat the iterations once for each index in the `index` array, you end up with the last found index (7 in your case).

```
for(int i = 0, x = 0; i < I.length; i++)  {
    if(I[i] == value) {
        index[x++] = i;
    }       
}
```